# Program received signal SIGABRT when run

Tags: xcode4

When I run this program, it always shows program received signal SIGABRT. Below is my code that I modify especially the AVAudioPlayer. Anything wrong with my code? What is the problem? Here is the breakpoint: `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);`

```
-(IBAction) start {
        {
         self.playBgMusic.enabled = YES;
        [self.player play];
        }   
    }

    -(IBAction) stop {
        {
            self.playBgMusic.enabled = NO;
            [self.player stop];
        }   
    }

    -(void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)completed 
    {
        if(completed == YES){
            self.playBgMusic.enabled = YES;
        }
    }


    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music" ofType:@"mp3"];
        self.player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL]; 
        player.delegate = self;
        [player play];
        player.numberOfLoops = -1;

        [super viewDidLoad];
    }


    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {  
        [player stop];
        [super viewDidUnload];

    }
```

Comment: You should post more information about the problem, not the program itself. SIGABRT is commonly seen and may be caused by a lot of things.
I suspect you do not know what is SIGABRT so you may read here:
[SIGABRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGABRT).

Other problems on the stack: [Other topics on SIGABRT in StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SIGABRT]) - may anwser you or at least they surely will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to retain `self.player`, although this isn't clear from your code. If you've defined `player` (correctly) as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

... then you have a different problem.

Comment: I already define player. Here is the breakpoint. int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);